# CSS Grid - Rules for a column that must be as narrow as possible but with a max width of 50%

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a very simple grid, with two columns. The left column is a picture and the right column is some text.

I want the left column to adjust to the picture width (so the column must be as narrow as possible, as long as the picture fits). But I also want this column to *take maximum 50% of the grid width*.

I tried a couple of things like:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 50%) 1fr;
```

But that doesn't work: the left column always takes 50%, even with a small picture!

So how can I tell it to take less width if the picture is smaller?

(Please note that the width of the picture is `max-width: 100%`)

Comment: this seems more suitable with flexbox by using max-width:50% on the image and flex-grow:1 on the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track, you can use a combination of `minmax()` and `max-content`.

Set the image column to a minimum of `auto` and a maximum of `max-content` while setting the text column to a minimum of `50%` and a maximum of `auto`.

```
grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, max-content) minmax(50%, auto);
```

The minimum of 50% on the text column will ensure that the picture is never wider than 50%, while the maximum of auto ensures that the text will grow larger when the image is less than 50% wide.

On the other hand, the minimum of auto on the image will ensure that it adjusts to fit to the image's size when less than 50%... while the maximum of max-content allows the text column to extend all the way passed 50% to meet the image's intrinsic width.

You could also use `fit-content()` for the image column instead of `minmax(auto, max-content)`, but that amounts to the same thing (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content).

Here a snippet:

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, max-content) minmax(50%, auto);

}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <img class="grid-item"src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
  <p class="grid-item">Some Text</p>
</div>
```

To test you can adjust the number at the end of the placeholder image URL to make it bigger or smaller. Here in fiddle form: https://jsfiddle.net/98gme470/

Note the lacking support for `max-content` and `fit-content()` in IE: https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content

Comment: This answer only works for the special case of two columns. If you have three columns, and the outer two need to be shrinkwrapped with a max width, you can't know what to put as the minimum for the middle column.

Comment: @75thTrombone I think that depends on the specific case. For example If your two outer columns are equal then grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, max-content) minmax(33.33%, auto) minmax(auto, max-content); works nicely for three even columns.